# Test onTap behaviour

Tags: flutter, testing, dart

I would like to test that when I am tapping a button, the user is routed to the next page. This works in the UI. I introduced the test but I get the following error:
`The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test: Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "MyNextView" (ignoring offstage widgets)> Which: means none were found but one was expected`

What am I doing wrong?

```
testWidgets('Button tap routes to next page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final button = createButton();
    await tester.pumpWidget(button);
    
    await tester.tap(find.byWidget(button));
    expect(find.byType(MyNextView), findsOneWidget);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After >

await tester.tap(find.byWidget(button));

Put this line >

await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Wait for screen to update

```
    testWidgets('Button tap routes to next page', (WidgetTester tester) async {
        final button = createButton();
        await tester.pumpWidget(button);

        await tester.tap(find.byWidget(button));

        await tester.pumpAndSettle(); // Wait for screen to update

        expect(find.byType(MyNextView), findsOneWidget);
      });
```

Comment: The order was wrong, until my edit is approved I'll leave this comment here: 
first tap then pumpAndSettle. This did it for me.

Comment: You are right, pumpAndSettle should be after tap. Don't know what I was thinking.